# Merge Excel rows based on common column values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, merge

I have a table similar to the image below. Column A has repeated values, while column B has values corresponding to column A. e.g. a single customer can have multiple orders.

[image]

What I would like to do is combine the rows, so that there is only one row per unique column A value (customer) and in the column B for that row, all column B values (orders) are gathered together in a comma separated list.

Answer (score 1):

Your results can be produced using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365.

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table29"]}[Content],

    //Note that we type "order" as text -- so as to be able to use in next step without converting.
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Customer", type text}, {"Order", type text}}),

    //Group rows and aggregate the text string
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Customer"}, {
        {"Order", each Text.Combine([Order],","), type text}
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

**Data and Results**
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm for combining customer data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Office 2019/365, the [TEXTJOIN function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) provides convenience for this.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(A:A=D2,B:B,""))
```

[image]

Comment: according to his tags, he's using 2013. But this might be good for another user searching for a solution.